# How to create columns from specific values per row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have similar df like below,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DRINKS':['WHISKEY','VODKA','WATER'],
                    'STRONG':[5,5,0],
                    'SOUR':[5,4,0]})
```

And I want to transform it to this one (Read 5s from the dataframe and when it matches, create a column with whatever name(I named it Cat1) and get the column name(STRONG) where the value was 5, then move on tho the next column and do the same operation until there no columns with rows with a value 5. The final outcome should be like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DRINKS':['WHISKEY','VODKA','WATER'],
                    'Cat1':["STRONG","STRONG",np.nan],
                    'Cat2':["SOUR",np.nan,np.nan]})
```

I tried to do it with

```
df['Cat1']=(df == 5).idxmax(axis=1)
```

but it gives me only 1 column name for Whiskey.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select and set all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:, :1].join(pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(5),df.columns[1:],np.nan),
                            index=df.index, 
                            columns=[f'Cat{i}' for i,_ in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 1)]))
print (df)
    DRINKS    Cat1  Cat2
0  WHISKEY  STRONG  SOUR
1    VODKA  STRONG   NaN
2    WATER     NaN   NaN
```

Or:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(5), df.columns[1:], np.nan)
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns[1:],
                               [f'Cat{i}' for i,_ in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 1)])))
print (df)
    DRINKS    Cat1  Cat2
0  WHISKEY  STRONG  SOUR
1    VODKA  STRONG   NaN
2    WATER     NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df['Cat1'] = np.where(df[df.columns[1]].eq(5), df.columns[1], np.nan) #or df['Cat1'] = np.where(df["STRONG"].eq(5), "STRONG", np.nan)
df['Cat2'] = np.where(df[df.columns[2]].eq(5), df.columns[2], np.nan) #or df['Cat2'] = np.where(df["SOUR"].eq(5), "SOUR", np.nan)

    DRINKS  STRONG  SOUR    Cat1    Cat2
0   WHISKEY 5       5       STRONG  SOUR
1   VODKA   5       4       STRONG  NaN
2   WATER   0       0       NaN     NaN

df = df.drop(columns=['STRONG', 'SOUR'])

    DRINKS  Cat1    Cat2
0   WHISKEY STRONG  SOUR
1   VODKA   STRONG  NaN
2   WATER   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but i have to create cat1 and cat2 automatically

Comment: can you explain what you mean by automatically

Answer (score 0):

You could map each column value of 5 to the column header.  The core part of that would be:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x.map({5:x.name}))
```

**Which delivers:**

```
   STRONG  SOUR
0  STRONG  SOUR
1  STRONG   NaN
2     NaN   NaN
```

Then you could put it all together with a column rename:

```
dfo = (
    pd.concat([df['DRINKS'],df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x.map({5:x.name}))
               .rename(columns=lambda x: f"Cat{df.columns.get_loc(x)}")], axis=1)
)

print(dfo)
```

**Result**

```
    DRINKS    Cat1  Cat2
0  WHISKEY  STRONG  SOUR
1    VODKA  STRONG   NaN
2    WATER     NaN   NaN
```

Comment: you could change the `rename` part to `.rename(columns=lambda x: f"Cat{df.columns.get_loc(x)}")` to get the exact result of OP.

Comment: @Rabinzel Good call.  That's better.  I updated my answer with that.